# ¿Como arreglar un comando de consola que he creado en symfony para buscar en la base de datos?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, symfony, consola

Buenas estoy haciendo un comando para la consola de symfony para que compare un determinado parametro contra la base de datos, y intente hacerlo como se hace en los controladores con el ->getDoctrine() pero como la clase extiende de Command y no de Controller me da el sigiente error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "App\Command\TrazaCommand".
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

class TrazaCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'Traza';

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setDescription('Add a short description for your command')
            ->addArgument('arg1', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Argument description')
            ->addOption('option1', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Option description')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        $manager=fopen('C:\xampp\htdocs\sgisi-master\public\x.txt','r');
        while (!feof($manager)){
            $cadena= fgets($manager);
            $cadena = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ', $cadena);
            $array=explode(" ", $cadena);
            if($array[3] == "TCP_MISS/200"){
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $url = ($array[6]);
                $urldb = $em->getRepository('App:URLExcluir')->findOneByURL($url);
                if (null != $urldb){
                    print_r ($array);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y como pueden ver en la funcion execute() intento comparar la url contenida en un array y guardada en $url contra una tabla de la base de datos, si alguien me pudiera decir como corregirlo se lo agradeceeria.

Answer (score 2):

Muy buenas,

Yo normalmente suelo extender mis comandos desde `ContainerAwareCommand`:

```
...

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

...

class EjemploCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
```

Con esto lo que consigo es poder acceder al `Container` de Symfony desde cualquier sitio dentro del comando, por ejemplo:

```
/** Obtengo un servicio o un repositorio **/
$this->getContainer()->get('servicio_o_repositorio');

/** Obtengo directamente Doctrine **/
$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda ;)

Answer (score 0):

La clase que extiendes en el controlador probablemente sea `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` en ella hay algunos atajos para acceder a los servicios más comunes, como `@doctrine`, `@session`, etc..
En este caso has creado un comando que es un tipo de servicio especial. 
La clase `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command` no tiene métodos mágicos para acceder al contenedor de servicios así que has de injectarle tú los servicios que necesitas:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class TrazaCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'Traza';

    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        parent::__construct(self::$defaultName);
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setDescription('Add a short description for your command')
            ->addArgument('arg1', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Argument description')
            ->addOption('option1', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Option description')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        $manager=fopen('C:\xampp\htdocs\sgisi-master\public\x.txt','r');

        $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('App:URLExcluir');
        while (!feof($manager)){
            $cadena= fgets($manager);
            $cadena = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ', $cadena);
            $array=explode(" ", $cadena);
            if($array[3] == "TCP_MISS/200"){
                $url = ($array[6]);
                $urldb = $repository->findOneByURL($url);
                if (null != $urldb){
                    print_r ($array);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si estás trabajando con la versión 4 de Symfony probablemente tengas el [autowiring   activado](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)

Si no es así tendrás que definir las dependencias del comando manualmente:

```
#app/config/services.yml
services:
    App\Command\TrazaCommand:
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
        tags:
            - { name: console.command}
```

Puedes encontrar más información de cómo funciona el contenedor de servicios aquí: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html